# Card component does not function properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a react component that shows a list of user data and images built with antd on nextJs. The reactions does not function as expected, all reactions and cards get clicked  all at once instead of individually. I want to get each reaction and card component to have its unique click instead of all at once. Here's also [a link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vynk6l2v80)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Avatar, Card, Icon, List  } from 'antd';

import { ICON_LIST, LIST_TEXTS, STYLES, USER_UPLOAD } from './constants';

const { AVATAR, CARD_CONTAINER, ICON, USER_LIST } = STYLES;
const { INNER, MORE, UPLOAD, VERTICAL } = LIST_TEXTS

class Home extends React.Component {
state = {
    clicks: 0,
};
IncrementIconText = () => {
    this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1 });
  }
render() {
    const actions = ( ICON_LIST.map(({ type }) => (
        <span>
            <Icon key={type} type={type} onClick={this.IncrementIconText} style={ICON} />
            {this.state.clicks}
        </span>
    )));
    return (
        <List
        itemLayout={VERTICAL}
        dataSource={USER_UPLOAD}
        renderItem={item => (
            <List.Item style={USER_LIST}>  
                <Card
                    actions={actions}
                    cover={<img alt={UPLOAD} src={item.image} />}
                    extra={<Icon type={MORE} />}
                    hoverable
                    title={<a><Avatar src={item.image} style={AVATAR} />{item.user}</a>}
                    type={INNER}
                    style={CARD_CONTAINER}
                >
                    {item.story}
                </Card>
            </List.Item>
        )}
        />
    );
}
}

export default Home;
```

constants.js

```
export const ICON_LIST = [
{
    key: "heart",
    type: "heart",
},
{
    key: "dislike",
    type: "dislike",
},

 {
    key: "meh",
    type: "meh",
},
]

export const LIST_TEXTS = {
INNER: "inner",
MORE: "more",
UPLOAD: "upload",
VERTICAL: "vertical",
};

export const STYLES = {
AVATAR: {
    marginRight: 8
},
CARD_CONTAINER: {
    width: "650px",
    marginBottom: 50
},
ICON: {
    marginRight: 8 
},
USER_LIST: {
    width: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
},
};

export const USER_UPLOAD = [
{
    image: "http://sugarweddings.com/files/styles/width-640/public/1.%20The%20Full%20Ankara%20Ball%20Wedding%20Gown%20@therealrhonkefella.PNG",
    story: "Today's my birthday next week! What do you think?",
    user: "Chioma",
},
{
    image: "https://dailymedia.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/7915550_img20181007141132_jpeg01c125e1588ffeee95a6f121c35cd378-1.jpg",
    story: "Going for an event. Do you like my outfit",
    user: "Simpcy",
},
{
    image: "https://i0.wp.com/www.od9jastyles.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/ankara-styles-ankara-styles-gown-ankara-tops-ankara-gowns-ankara-styles-pictures-latest-ankara-style-2018-latest-ankara-styles-ankara-ankara-styles.png?fit=437%2C544&ssl=1",
    story: "Saturdays are for weddings. Yay or nay!",
    user: "Angela",
},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you have a single piece of state (`clicks`) that is put on each icon. This is the same piece of state and the same handler for every icon, on every card.

To get your desired functionality, you will need a different count for every icon.

Here is an example of how to do that (I forked your codesandbox): https://codesandbox.io/s/pyj2288l0

Also, for state updates that depend on previous state, you should use `this.setState((prevState) => {...})`. This is because state change can be asynchronous and `this.state` isn't guaranteed to be the one you expect. Here are the docs on why you need that: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: At this current state, I can click as many times as I want, I also want to ensure that once I click one icon in an element, clicking another one withdraws the previous one and double clicking revokes what was clicked

Comment: You will have to add handlers and business logic to do that

Answer (score 0):

No matter which icon you click on, all you are doing is incrementing the state of "clicks" and applying that state to all of your icons. So that is the why the click count is the same across all of your icons on each click. There should be a different "clicks" state counter for each individual icon the user can click on.

Answer (score 0):

You almost are ready to get the task you just have to add counters for every icon to get state separate and call the state according to the type of icon,  a tiny implementation could be:

```
import React from "react";
import { Avatar, Card, Icon, List } from "antd";

import { ICON_LIST, LIST_TEXTS, STYLES, USER_UPLOAD } from "./constants";

const { AVATAR, CARD_CONTAINER, ICON, USER_LIST } = STYLES;
const { INNER, MORE, UPLOAD, VERTICAL } = LIST_TEXTS;

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    clicks: 0,
    heartClicks: 0,
    dislikeClicks: 0,
    emojiClicks: 0
  };

  IncrementIconText = type => {
    if (type === "heart") {
      this.setState({ heartClicks: this.state.heartClicks + 1 });
    } else if (type === "dislike") {
      this.setState({ dislikeClicks: this.state.dislikeClicks + 1 });
    } else if (type === "meh") {
      this.setState({ emojiClicks: this.state.emojiClicks + 1 });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const actions = ICON_LIST.map(({ type }) => (
      <span>
        <Icon
          key={type}
          type={type}
          onClick={() => this.IncrementIconText(type)}
          style={ICON}
        />
        {type === "heart"
          ? this.state.heartClicks
          : type === "dislike"
          ? this.state.dislikeClicks
          : this.state.emojiClicks}
      </span>
    ));
    return (
      <List
        itemLayout={VERTICAL}
        dataSource={USER_UPLOAD}
        renderItem={item => (
          <List.Item style={USER_LIST}>
            <Card
              actions={actions}
              cover={<img alt={UPLOAD} src={item.image} />}
              extra={<Icon type={MORE} />}
              hoverable
              title={
                <a>
                  <Avatar src={item.image} style={AVATAR} />
                  {item.user}
                </a>
              }
              type={INNER}
              style={CARD_CONTAINER}
            >
              {item.story}
            </Card>
          </List.Item>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: This solution will give the same count to all icons that are the same on every photo.

i.e. clicking heart on one photo will update the heart count on all photos.